# How to concatenate elements of a single-dimensional array using VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, join, outlook

I'm trying to loop through email messages in Outlook, scrap unique ID numbers and concatenate them as one string.

Each message contains several different IDs that are multiplied across the email, like these:

```
ID 1111, ID 2222
ID 1111, ID 33333, ID 2222
ID 1111, ID 2222, ID 444, ID 33333
ID 2222, ID 1111
```

Then expected result would be (sorted):

```
ID 444, ID 1111, ID 2222, ID 33333
```

Here is my code.

```
Sub Scrap_IDs()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application: Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim olFolder As MAPIFolder: Set olFolder = olApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Folder_name")

    Dim olMail As Variant: For Each olMail In olFolder.Items
        Dim mBody As String: mBody = olMail.Body
    
        With olMail
        ' Scrap all IDs using regex
             With New RegExp
                    .Global = True
                    .Pattern = "ID[ \d]+"
            
            Dim MatchID As Object: For Each MatchID In .Execute(mBody)
                    Dim i As Long: Dim arrMatchID(): ReDim Preserve arrMatchID(i)
                    arrMatchID(i) = MatchID.Value
                    i = i + 1
                Next
            End With
            
        ' Remove duplicates from array
            Dim RemArrDups As Variant: RemArrDups = WorksheetFunction.Sort(WorksheetFunction.Unique(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrMatchID)))
    
        ' Concatenate array items
            Dim IDs As String: IDs = Join(RemArrDups, ", ")
    
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

The line related to concatenation gives run-time error 5 "Invalid procedure call or argument". Why is that?

It works if I use the Join function on `arrMatchID` instead of `RemArrDups`, but this way the values won't be unique.

Comment: `RemArrDups` needs to be an array, not just declared as a variant.

Comment: Thanks! But how to make it an array?

Comment: @SJR A variable declared as variant can perfectly hold an array too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Microsoft 365's `UNIQUE` and `SORT` in VBA

```vb
' This is a 1D array, a single row.
Dim arrMatchId(): arrMatchId = Array( _
    "ID 667", "ID 3", "ID 1111", "ID 2222", "ID 3", "ID 44", "ID 667")

' Remove duplicates and sort the array.
' Keep it a single row (don't transpose). Use 'True' as the parameters
' for the 'col' arguments of both functions.
Dim RemArrDups(): RemArrDups _
    = Application.Sort(Application.Unique(arrMatchId, True), , , True)

' Join.
Dim IDs As String: IDs = Join(RemArrDups, ", ")

Debug.Print IDs
```

Comment: Modified my line of code using your suggestion and it worked. Thank you. `Dim RemArrDups As Variant: RemArrDups = WorksheetFunction.Sort(WorksheetFunction.Unique(arrMatchID, True), , , True)`